# How do I find the equation of a predicted logistic curve?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, equation, predict

Using R, I would like input on how to find the equation of a predicted logistic curve (predicted from empirical data).

The closest command I could find is the `stat_poly_eq` function from the `library(ggpmisc)` and used when plotting the curves with ggplot2. However, I can only get this method to print a y = 0.48 on the graph, but I want the whole equation.

Here is some R code for reference:

```
 gg.disp.adults<- ggplot(sub.data, aes(x=SVL3, y=Disp01)) +
   geom_point(size=4) +
   stat_smooth( aes(y= Disp01), method="glm", method.args=list(family="binomial"), se=F) +
   stat_poly_eq(aes(label=paste(..eq.label..,..rr.label..,sep="~~~~")), 
           rr.digits=3, coef.digits=2,
           formula = y~1/(1+exp(-x)), 
           parse = TRUE) +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=14, color="black"),
    axis.text.y=element_text(size=14, color="black"), 
    axis.line=element_line(size=1), 
    axis.title.x=element_text(size=14), 
    axis.title.y=element_text(size=14),
    panel.background=element_rect(fill="white")) +
ylab("Dispersal Probability") +
ylim(0,1)+
xlab("Adult SVL")
gg.disp.adults
```

[image: plot]

Please advise on how to go about obtaining the actual equation for the predicted curve.

EDIT:

I was able to find the equation of the predicted curve using the coefficients from the output summary, and applying it to a standard logistic equation: 
y ~ 1/(1+exp(-x)). Here is the R code for reference:

```
 Call:
 glm(formula = Disp01 ~ SVL3, family = binomial, data = sub.data)

 Deviance Residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
 -2.1207  -0.8812  -0.4844   0.8885   1.9168  

 Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
 (Intercept) -12.1800     3.6968  -3.295 0.000985 ***
 SVL3          0.1845     0.0561   3.289 0.001006 ** 
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 x<- seq(50,80,1)
 y<- 1/(1+exp(-(0.1845*x-12.18))) #coefficients from glm2 output
 plot(y~x, typ="l", ylim=c(0,1))
 points(Disp01~SVL3, data=sub.data, pch=16, cex=1.5)
```

...I am unable to post a photo of the new predicted curve.

Answer (score 1):

Since `stat_smooth` is just running `glm(y ~ x, ...)` on your data, you can do the same to recover the model estimates.  Here's an example with some made up data:

Make up data:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100, 0, 2))
d$y <- rbinom(100, 1, plogis(d$x))
```

Fit using `glm`.  `fit` will therefore report the equation that you want:

```
fit <- glm(y ~ x, data = d, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
fitted <- data.frame(x = d$x, y = predict(fit, type = "response"))
```

Here we can see that predicted values from `fitted` match up exactly with the `stat_smooth` line:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) +
  stat_smooth(method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial")) +
  geom_point(data = fitted, aes(x, y))
```

[image]